# Neo4j server is not starting

Tags: neo4j

I'm unable to start Neo4j server. Frequently I'm receiving a GC overhead limit exceeded and Java class not fount exception:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.desktop.Neo4jDesktop

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Can you share the version of Neo4j and which OS you are using (and whether you are using an exe, zip or package installation) ?

Comment: I 'am using Neo4j 3.2.2 in windows OS and i' am using .exe installation

Comment: Can you share the output of the following command ?
C:\Users\youruser> java -version

Comment: java -version is 1.8.0_121